# Zoom to boundries in Google Maps Lite mode

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any way to zoom to boundries using Google Maps Lite for Android? I was trying to use the `newLatLngBounds` function -

```
  public void moveToArea(GoogleMap map, Polygon polygon){
        if(map != null && polygon != null) {
            LatLngBounds bounds = null;
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (LatLng point : polygon.getPoints()) {
                builder.include(point);
                bounds = builder.build();
            }
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, Sizes.dpToPx(100, ctx), Sizes.dpToPx(100, ctx), 30));
         } 
    }
```

But I am getting this: `Google Maps Android API﹕ newLatLngBounds with size is not supported in Lite Mode`. So, how to zoom to specified bounds in Lite Mode?

Comment: Not all Google Maps API features are supported in Lite Mode, you might want to try using the `public static CameraUpdate newLatLngBounds (LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)` method, which it does not need width and heigh parameters, and it can still zoom to a specific bounds.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, as the zoom level is not consistent enough?